# Angular positioned map goes blank after browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, laravel-9

In my system in Laravel 9 I have a LeafLet map. It works fine with some exeptions.

Looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcuVr.jpg

A controller (CompetitionsMapController.php) has this code:

```
    {
        $data = Competition::all();
        return view('map', ['data'=> $data]);
    }
```

This is the link in navigation blade:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': (currentRoute=='competition.map')}">
     <a ui-sref="map">{{_('MAP')}}</a>
 </li>
```

and in the public/js/app.js:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('map', {
        url: '/map',
        parent: 'root',

        views: {
            'content@':  {
                templateUrl: 'map'
            },       
        },
        restricted: true
    });
```

This works fine but if I refresh the browser the map goes blank.
Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMM68.jpg
I have to enter another choice on navigation bar and back to the MAP to show the map again. I have tried with Google Map and that works Ok with browser refresh but not this LeafLet map. Also if I put a simple javascript file in there itself works even after refresh so it must have to do with LeafLet map script.

The LeafLet map script:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([57.36,15.26], 7);
          mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
          L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);
```

So I wonder what could be the problem and what can fix it?

I found out an error in Safari:

```
Error: Can't find variable: L
eval code@
eval@[native code]
globalEval@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:1:14516
M@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:1:4621
append@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:2:22024
@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:2:23130
$e@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:2:9577
html@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:2:22802
@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:22:14027
ye@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:5:795
f@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:4:25187
o@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:4:20911
@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:4:20442
c@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:22:13517
@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:22:13786
$broadcast@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:6:4545
@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:22:9167
o@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:5:27411
@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:5:27583
$digest@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:6:1689
$apply@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:6:3444
u@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:5:9841
b@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:5:11764
@http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/vendor.js:5:12237 – "<div ui-view=\"content\" class=\"ng-scope\" data-ng-animate=\"1\">"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. When choosing the map in the navigation another blade is also loaded, app.blade.php, and putting:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

into there the map gets updated ok. That's all that's needed.